# Sending values from JavaScript to php file depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm sending values from Javascript to php file, It's working fine when all values have been collected.

Step1 is working fine because both fields are mandatory, while in step2 it's sending values when all the fields are selected. But in step2 there are some conditional element like first option pillers "yes" is, it does't ask for second value,but my code expecting all the values together to be send, how can i send values depending on the user selection and other values to false or null?

```
function btnSubmit(step,userid)
{

 //If Step 1
    if(step == 'step1') {
        var Name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var DoB = document.getElementById("thedate").value;
        //Create a Variable catVar Having the Var Name and Var DoB Concatinated with a --

        var catVar = Name + "--" + DoB;

    }
    else if(step == 'step2') {

         var pillers = document.getElementById("point1pillers").value;
         var pillersthird = document.getElementById("point3pillers").value;
         var  old = (document.querySelector("[name=status2]:checked").value);
         var  together = (document.querySelector("[name=status3]:checked").value);
         var  left = (document.querySelector("[name=status4]:checked").value);

         var catVar = pillers + "--" + pillersthird + "--" + old + "--" + together + "--" + left;
    }
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/wp-content/themes/xerius_main/kinderbijslag_calculator/validations/btnSubmit.php?q="+step+"&q2="+userid+"&q3="+catVar,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You can maybe just put a condition after getting pillers to change catVar value.
So you can have a good URL in all cases.

Comment: @Johnny_H can you please give me hint how can write condition here? I got your point but i have no clue. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the question is kind of weird, because it sounds like you're asking about basic `if` stuff and string composition, yet you're already using both. Where exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far? Why not simply set `old` to null `if` something else is true? (and why have you tagged this with [tag:jQuery] yet aren't using any of it, which would make your code considerably shorter? Also, the question isn't about sending values to PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just set the default value for all variables as null if the values are not set and the checkbox is not checked Hope it helps you**

```
    if(step == 'step2') {
    var pillers = document.getElementById("point1pillers").value;
    if (pillers.length < 1)
        pillers = null;
    var pillersthird = document.getElementById("point3pillers").value;
    if (pillersthird.length < 1)
        pillersthird = null;
    var old = (document.querySelector("[name=status2]:checked") != null ?
        document.querySelector("[name=status2]:checked").value : null);

    var together = (document.querySelector("[name=status3]:checked") != null ? document.querySelector("[name=status3]:checked").value : null);

    var left = (document.querySelector("[name=status4]:checked") != null ? document.querySelector("[name=status4]:checked").value : null);


    var catVar = pillers + "--" + pillersthird + "--" + old + "--" + together + "--" + left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check what values q3 parameter of the url can take.
But for your question you could try to test pillers value

```
  var pillers = document.getElementById("point1pillers").value;
    var catVars = '';
    if (pillers === 'yes') {
        // get other fields
        catVar = pillers + "--" + pillersthird + "--" + old + "--" + together + "--" + left;
    } else {
        // get other fields
        catVars = 'the value when pillers is not yes'; 
    }
```